# PHP function seems to just stop half way

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below PHP function I have written. It's to create a new database table and insert some values to it and another table.

```
function createTable($tablename, $mins){
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","*****");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $tableCreate = "CREATE TABLE rates_{$tablename} (
                                              Weight int(11),
                                              CBMMin double,
                                              CBMMax double,
                                              Min double
                                              )";
        $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, $tableCreate);
        if ($queryResult === TRUE) {
            print "<br /><br />Table Created";
        } else {
            print "<br /><br />No TABLE created. Check " . mysqli_error($con);
        }
        //Echo/print stop working here but below query does fire
        $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Custom_Rates (TableName) VALUES ('rates_{$tablename}');");
        //everything below here does not 
        $rows = array(
                array('weight' => 1000, 'cbm_min' => 0.1, 'cbm_max' => 2.3 ),
                array('weight' => 1500, 'cbm_min' => 2.31, 'cbm_max' => 3.5 ),
                array('weight' => 2000, 'cbm_min' => 3.51, 'cbm_max' => 4.6 ),
                array('weight' => 2500, 'cbm_min' => 4.61, 'cbm_max' => 5.75 ),
                array('weight' => 3000, 'cbm_min' => 5.75, 'cbm_max' => 6.9 ),
                );
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'rates_".$tablename."' (Weight, CBMMin, CBMMax) VALUES (".$row['weight'].",".$row['cbm_min'].",".$row['cbm_max'].");");
            if ($queryResult === TRUE) {
                print "<br /><br />Row Created";
            } else {
                print "<br /><br />No Row created. Check " . mysqli_error($con);
            }
        }
```

It seems like the for each loop simple does not get fired as neither the true or false if statements get fired as nothing gets printed.
I had added extra print statements to debug what is actually carried out last and it seems after the

```
$queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Custom_Rates (TableName)
VALUES ('rates_{$tablename}');");
```

line nothing else happens (And I know that this query works because I can see the date in the rates table).

Any ideas as to what could be stopping the foreach from working?

Comment: Try adding error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); on top of your code and post the result

Comment: take the query and echo the whole query string then try in mysql console

Comment: So does it step into foreach? I mean does $row get a value assigned?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius it would seem to not step in at all, i.e I placed an echo in the first line of the foreach before the query but it does not output

Comment: Do people still concatenate strings to use as queries?

Comment: 1) var_dump($row) in foreach to see it it fires 2) try $queryResult !== false instead

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was that the php max_execution_time is to low for the script, or that the connection will lost during the operation. Try a set_time_limit(0) to deactivate teh time limit.

Its only a first idea

Comment: doing this makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems to have just started working, wondering if there was an issue with the web server or something else, anyway thanks for everyone's input